# TinyMCE "Add Class" Input Field to Link Dialog

Tags: class, tinymce, tinymce-4

link_class_list plugin allows to create a list of classes to choose when adding a link. Is there a way to add an open input instead of a dropdown so the user can enter any class?

These are the parameters on the documentation but there isn't any mention regarding an open input field.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "link",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "link",
  link_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
    {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
  ]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',
 menubar:false,
 plugins: [
  'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
  'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
  'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor code pageembed codesample advcode '
 ],
 toolbar: 'bold italic | link image preview media fullpage pageembed | code codesample forecolor backcolor | emoticons styleselect alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist outdent indent |table tabledelete | tableprops tablerowprops tablecellprops | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol',
        default_link_target: '_blank',
        style_formats: [{title: 'Button (Default)', selector: 'a', classes: ''}, {title: 'Button (primary)', selector: 'a', classes: 'btn btn-primary'}, {title: 'Button (success)', selector: 'a', classes: 'btn btn-success'}],
        link_class_list: [{title:'Button (Default)', value:''}, {title:'Button (primary)', value:'btn btn-primary'}, {title:'Button (success)', value:'btn btn-success'}]

});
</script>
```

Try this.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.